# Why Service Bus Output binding is not working for Azure Functions? - No errors

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I try to send HTTPTriggered message to Service Bus Output. 
I'm following sample of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-output?tabs=csharp

I get no error when I execute this code from Visual Studio Code.
In this I'm debugging locally.

However Service Bus Portal says there is 0 incoming message. What could be wrong?
Is there issue with code?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;
using Microsoft.ServiceBus;


namespace Company.Function
{
    public static class HttpTriggerCSharp1
    {
    [FunctionName("ServiceBusOutput")]

    [return: ServiceBus("queue1", Connection ="Endpoint=sb://12345servicebus.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=12345+cmc8501HJ6Ips2OxIZKtO6gctT8d1ZpNN0GNw=")]
    public static string ServiceBusOutput([HttpTrigger] dynamic input, ILogger log)
    {

        //log.LogInformation($"C# function processed: {input.Text}");
        //return input.Text;
        return "MessageToServiceBus123"
    }
}
```

}

```
Http Functions:

        ServiceBusOutput:  http://localhost:7071/api/ServiceBusOutput

[10.3.2020 21.35.37] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '0000000000000000000000008457DB20'.
[10.3.2020 21.35.44] Executing HTTP request: {
[10.3.2020 21.35.44]   "requestId": "0ccbb526-b861-407a-893c-cc0821b20535",
[10.3.2020 21.35.44]   "method": "GET",
[10.3.2020 21.35.44]   "uri": "/api/ServiceBusOutput"
[10.3.2020 21.35.44] }
[10.3.2020 21.35.45] Executing 'ServiceBusOutput' (Reason='This function was programmatically called 
via the host APIs.', Id=faf4083f-504a-473b-b9fa-22ac0783cdb0)
[10.3.2020 21.35.45] Executed 'ServiceBusOutput' (Succeeded, Id=faf4083f-504a-473b-b9fa-22ac0783cdb0)
[10.3.2020 21.35.45] Executed HTTP request: {
[10.3.2020 21.35.45]   "requestId": "0ccbb526-b861-407a-893c-cc0821b20535",
[10.3.2020 21.35.45]   "method": "GET",
[10.3.2020 21.35.45]   "uri": "/api/ServiceBusOutput",
[10.3.2020 21.35.45]   "identities": [
[10.3.2020 21.35.45]     {
[10.3.2020 21.35.45]       "type": "WebJobsAuthLevel",
[10.3.2020 21.35.45]       "level": "Admin"
[10.3.2020 21.35.45]     }
[10.3.2020 21.35.45]   ],
[10.3.2020 21.35.45]   "status": 200,
[10.3.2020 21.35.45]   "duration": 906
[10.3.2020 21.35.45] }
[10.3.2020 21.35.45] Executing HTTP request: {
[10.3.2020 21.35.45]   "requestId": "d2587ceb-f728-4cda-be99-ff7852384a59",
[10.3.2020 21.35.45]   "method": "GET",
[10.3.2020 21.35.45]   "uri": "/favicon.ico"
[10.3.2020 21.35.45] }
[10.3.2020 21.35.46] Executed HTTP request: {
[10.3.2020 21.35.46]   "requestId": "d2587ceb-f728-4cda-be99-ff7852384a59",
[10.3.2020 21.35.46]   "method": "GET",
[10.3.2020 21.35.46]   "uri": "/favicon.ico",
[10.3.2020 21.35.46]   "identities": [],
[10.3.2020 21.35.46]   "status": 404,
[10.3.2020 21.35.46]   "duration": 645
[10.3.2020 21.35.46] }
```

Comment: You should set connection key-value in loca.settings.json, and put key in the binding not the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the document says,

> You can set the Connection property to specify the name of an app
>   setting that contains the Service Bus connection string to use

You should set connection string value as a key value pair in local.settings.json and mention the key

For ex,

```
[FunctionName("ServiceBusOutput")]
[return: ServiceBus("myqueue", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")]
public static string Run([HttpTrigger] dynamic input, ILogger log)
```

**Local.settings.json**

```
{  
  "ServiceBusConnection": "whatever connection string"
}
```